# npoi not add cells near merged cells

Tags: c#, excel, apache-poi, npoi

Hello I use npoi (Port of Apache Poi to .NET) to make many report

I need make a Excel like this [image: Example]

Where *x1, x2 , x3* .. are dynamically added in *row 15* `Level | Name | CT | CH | C` are repeated for each item

I have this code

```
int nrow = 13;

row = (HSSFRow)sheet.CreateRow(nrow);
rowBottom = (HSSFRow)sheet.CreateRow(nrow + 1);
ncol = 0;

foreach (Plan plan in planesUltimos) {

    var i = ncol + 1;

    cell = (HSSFCell)rowBottom.CreateCell(i++);
    cell.SetCellValue("Level");    

    cell = (HSSFCell)rowBottom.CreateCell(i++);
    cell.SetCellValue("Name");

    cell = (HSSFCell)rowBottom.CreateCell(i++);
    cell.SetCellValue("CT");

    cell = (HSSFCell)rowBottom.CreateCell(i++);
    cell.SetCellValue("CH");

    cell = (HSSFCell)rowBottom.CreateCell(i);
    cell.SetCellValue("C");

    var cellRange=  new CellRangeAddress(nrow, nrow, ncol + 1, ncol + 5);

    sheet.AddMergedRegion(cellRange);

    HSSFRegionUtil.SetBorderBottom(NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.Medium, cellRange, sheet, wb);
    HSSFRegionUtil.SetBorderTop(NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.Medium, cellRange, sheet, wb);
    HSSFRegionUtil.SetBorderRight(NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.Medium, cellRange, sheet, wb);
    HSSFRegionUtil.SetBorderLeft(NPOI.SS.UserModel.BorderStyle.Medium, cellRange, sheet, wb);


    cell = (HSSFCell)row.CreateCell(ncol + 1);
    cell.SetCellValue(plan.nombre);    

    ncol += 5;
}
```

But I get this

[image: example 2]

As seen in the image:

- first cell of each range not show border
- second rowBottom is not showing

I did a test

Change the rowBottom

```
rowBottom = (HSSFRow)sheet.CreateRow(nrow + 1);
```

To

```
rowBottom = (HSSFRow)sheet.CreateRow(nrow + 2);
```

And rowBottom is now in report

[image: example 3]

**But I need together**

No I'm doing wrong, there is another problem, in Excel when a change the aling in a row these lose borders

[image: example 4]

**EDIT**

I comment

```
//cell = (HSSFCell)row.CreateCell(ncol + 1);
//cell.SetCellValue(plan.nombre);
```

and tun it with `rowBottom = (HSSFRow)sheet.CreateRow(nrow + 1);`
[image: example 5]

Ranges have good borders,but still missing the *bottom row*

Comment: I suggest you getting rid of `CreateRow` and `CreateCell`, because these methods adds new ranges. And your goal is to do procedures with existing cells/rows. I don't know which command in NPOI sets existing range to a variable, but I see you used `CellRangeAddress` successfully. Regarding no boarders on the second line, I see that `var cellRange=  new CellRangeAddress(nrow, nrow, ncol + 1, ncol + 5);` has only one row, this is why you don't get the border.